# "PBRequester failed with Error Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1000 "bad URL"

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, mkmapview, geocoding

I have tested `mapview` with reverse geocoding location in iOS 7 devices and i get the following error:

> PBRequester failed with Error Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1000 "bad URL"

but on an iOS 8 device it's working fine. What can I do to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I was able resolve this error by updating the scheme options to Allow Location Services and set a default location.

In Xcode, go to Product>Scheme>Edit Scheme.  Under Run>Options, make sure the "Allow Location Simulation" is checked, then set a default Location.